# Openerp 7: workflow stops when given access rights

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I have created my own model for Monthly Appraisal with simple workflow.

[image]

1. Any employee can create Monthly evaluation save it and submit (draft --> confirm --> validate1) it.
2. Submitted evaluation will acknowledge by supervisor (validate 1 --> validate)

I create that part successfully and once I giving access rights to normal user it stops the workflow at submit (confirm -->validate1) button. Once I connect the normal profile to a admin profile it again working smoothly.

Please help me to solve this since I can't imagine what I did wrong.

***Workflow functions***

```
  def evaluation_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        #self.hr_mnthly_evaluation(cr, uid, ids, context=context)

        eval_id=self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0],context=context).evaluation_id
        eval_state=self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0],context=context).state


        values = {}
        values.update({'state':'confirm'})
        ime_super_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids ,context) 

        emp_id = ime_super_obj[0].employee_id.id
        emp_obj=self.pool.get('hr.employee')


        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'confirm'})


    def evaluation_first_validate(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

        values = {}
        values.update({'state':'validate1'})
        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, values)

    def evaluation_validate(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):


        obj_emp = self.pool.get('hr.employee')
        state = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0],context=context).state
        sup_id=self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0],context=context).parent_id.id

        idss = obj_emp.search(cr, uid, [('user_id', '=', uid)])
        log_user_uid=self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0],context=context).employee_id.id



        if (idss[0]==log_user_uid)and(state!='confirm'):
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_('You are not allow to acknowledge your own appraisals'))


        if idss[0]!=sup_id:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_('Only Immediate Supervisor , can acknowledge the appraisals !'))


        obj_emp = self.pool.get('hr.employee')

        idss = obj_emp.search(cr, uid, [('user_id', '=', uid)])

        values = {}
        values.update({'state':'validate'})
        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, values)


    def evaluation_refuse(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        print "workflow validate"
        values = {}
        values.update({'state':'refuse'})
        return self.write(cr, uid, ids, values)
```

***Given Access Rights***

[image]

***Given Record Rules***

[image]

**Once I click on "Submit"(Confirm) button the log looks like**
[image]

***Workflow***

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<openerp>
<data>

    <record model="workflow" id="wkf_mnthly_evaluation">
        <field name="name">hr.wkf.mnthly.evaluation</field>
        <field name="osv">hr.mnthly.evaluation</field>
        <field name="on_create">True</field>
    </record>

    <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_draft"> <!-- draft -->
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mnthly_evaluation" />
        <field name="flow_start">True</field>
        <field name="name">draft</field>
    </record>

    <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_confirm"> <!-- confirm -->
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mnthly_evaluation" />
        <field name="name">confirm</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">evaluation_confirm()</field>
        <field name="split_mode">OR</field>
    </record>

    <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_validate1"> <!-- first_validate -->
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mnthly_evaluation" />
        <field name="name">validate1</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">evaluation_first_validate()</field>
        <field name="split_mode">OR</field>
    </record>




    <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_validate"> <!-- validate -->
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mnthly_evaluation" />
        <field name="name">validate</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">evaluation_validate()</field>
    </record>


    <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_refuse"> <!-- refused -->
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_mnthly_evaluation" />
        <field name="name">refuse</field>
        <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        <field name="kind">function</field>
        <field name="action">evaluation_refuse()</field>
    </record>

    <!--
        workflow transition
    -->

    <record model="workflow.transition" id="evaluation_draft2confirm"> <!-- 1. draft->confirm (Save BTN - no action) -->
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_draft" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_confirm" />
    </record>

    <record model="workflow.transition" id="evaluation_confirm2validate1"> <!-- 2. confirm->validate1 (Request Confirm BTN)-->
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_confirm" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_validate1" />
        <field name="signal">validate1</field>

        <field name="group_id" ref="base.group_hr_user"/>
    </record>

    <record model="workflow.transition" id="evaluation_validate12validate2"> <!-- 2. validate1 -> validate2 (Manager Approval BTN)-->
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_validate1" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_validate" />
        <field name="signal">validate2</field>
         <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="group_id" ref="base.group_hr_user"/>
    </record>






<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->



    <record model="workflow.transition" id="evaluation_confirm2refuse"> <!-- 2. submitted->refused (refuse signal) -->
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_confirm" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_refuse" />
        <field name="signal">refuse</field>
        <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="group_id" ref="base.group_hr_user"/>
    </record>

    <record model="workflow.transition" id="evaluation_validate12refuse"> <!-- 2. submitted->refused (refuse signal) -->
        <field name="act_from" ref="act_validate1" />
        <field name="act_to" ref="act_refuse" />
        <field name="signal">refuse</field>
        <field name="condition">True</field>
        <field name="group_id" ref="base.group_hr_user"/>
    </record>




</data>
</openerp>
```

***Buttons***

```
        <header>
            <button string="Submit" name="validate1" states="confirm" type="workflow" class="oe_highlight"/>
            <button string="Manager Acknowledgement" name="validate2" states="validate1" type="workflow" class="oe_highlight" />

            <button string="Refuse" name="refuse" states="validate1" type="workflow"/>                    
            <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,confirm,validate1,validate" statusbar_colors='{"confirm":"blue","validate1":"blue","refuse":"red"}'/>
        </header>
```

Comment: Can you add the log output.

Comment: @Zety Log attached

Comment: Did you create a workflow transition for `confirm` to `validate` state ?

Comment: yes I did. When I connect it to just admin user account it works nicely

Comment: Please show the workflow code and the related buttons.

Comment: Added workflow code

Answer (score 0):

Changing workflow state to `validate` requires to be member of `base.group_hr_user`.

It worked when logging with admin user and not with a a normal user because `record rules do not apply to the Administrator user` (although access rules do).

Just add user to `base.group_hr_user` and give him access to the model then he should be able to change workflow state from `validate1` to `validate`.

Comment: I removed that part from the workflow code but still it's not working...still stuck in at draft

Comment: Delete workflow and update module (you can uninstall and reinstall the module).

Comment: Did this work for you (In my server, your code is working)?